# Can’t write to a file owned by the process with correct pemissions (may be selinux related)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, selinux, ubuntu-9.10

I've got bind setup on a fresh install of Ubuntu Karmic

I am trying to send bind some updates, but it fails with this message appearing in the logs

```
kernel: [254421.299955] type=1503 audit(1260156728.002:104): operation="mknod" pid=1111 parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/named" requested_mask="w::" denied_mask="w::" fsuid=105 ouid=105 name="/etc/bind/primary/db.nodomainname.com.jnl"
```

It seems to be selinux related, but I don't have selinux setup on the machine

Comment: Are you sure that SElinux is disabled?  What's the output of `getenforce`?

Comment: It says 'Disabled'

Comment: Output of `ps aux |grep bind` and `ls -ld /etc/bind/primary` plz

Comment: ps aux |grep bind
  bind      1483  0.2  0.5 201952 23504 ?        Ssl  14:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/named -u bind

    ls -ld /etc/bind/primary
    drwxr-sr-x 2 bind bind 4096 2009-12-04 16:07 /etc/bind/primary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install bind with Ubuntu's package management or from source? Maybe [AppArmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor) is kicking in?

Comment: Yes, it was AppArmour getting in the way